Does the YHWH reference in Acts 2:34 refer to the Trinity or to the Father?
Previous questions have asked:
- Who are the two "Lords" in Acts 2:34?
- What does "The LORD said to my Lord" mean in Psalm 110?
- What is Jesus' purpose in asking about Psalm 110?
And these have explored the relationship between the terms YHWH and Adonai in Psalm 110:1 and Acts 2:34, with most of the focus being on Peter's (or Jesus's) identification of Jesus as the Adonai or lord who was in-view in Psalm 110:1.
However, what I have not seen addressed is whom does Peter have in-view in Acts 2:34 when he refers to the Psalm's YHWH. Is he identifying YHWH with the Trinity or with the Father?
Since Peter is shifting (or clarifying) the referent of Adonai, is he also shifting (or clarifying) the referent of YHWH, at least for his understanding of Psalm 110:1?
The concept of the Trinity is a NT concept, although there is talk of the Spirit of God in the OT, but not so much as a distinct person, but more as the active force of the monotheistic God. But then we get into passages like John 3:17 and Matthew 28:19, and this Trinity concept becomes more pronounced. So, is Peter emphasizing not only the distinctness of Jesus in Acts 2:34, but also recasting our understanding of the term YHWH?

33 Being therefore exalted at the right hand of God, and having received from the Father the promise of the Holy Spirit, he has poured out this that you yourselves are seeing and hearing. 34 For David did not ascend into the heavens, but he himself says, “ ‘The Lord said to my Lord (Εἶπεν ὁ κύριος τῷ κυρίῳ μου), “Sit at my right hand, 35 until I make your enemies your footstool.” ’ 36 Let all the house of Israel therefore know for certain that God has made him both Lord and Christ, this Jesus whom you crucified.” (Acts 2:33–36 ESV)

Where this draws from:

1 The LORD says to my Lord: “Sit at my right hand, until I make your enemies your footstool.” 2 The LORD sends forth from Zion your mighty scepter. Rule in the midst of your enemies! 3 Your people will offer themselves freely on the day of your power, in holy garments; from the womb of the morning, the dew of your youth will be yours. 4 The LORD has sworn and will not change his mind, “You are a priest forever after the order of Melchizedek.” (Psalm 110:1–4 ESV)


Part of your question that asks "Is he identifying YHWH with the Trinity or with the Father?" needs to be clarified. Is there any record identifying YHWH with the trinity?

@AlexBalilo. Christians commonly understand the YHWH of Deuteronomy 6:4 to be referring to the unified godhead; namely, the Trinity. Therefore, I'm not following what needs to be clarified. E.g., Mark J. Boda, “Biblical Theology and Old Testament Biblical Theology and Old Testament Interpretation,” in Hearing the Old Testament: Listening for God’s Address, ed. Craig G. Bartholomew and David J. H. Beldman (Grand Rapids, MI: Eerdmans, 2012), 144.

The shema does not expressly state that God is the trinity. Jews[Jesus included] worship what they know. It would have confused the Jews to explain the assumption that their God/YHWH is really the trinity. Is the God of Israel really a mystifyingly multi-person God?

Sounds like we're getting into a Jewish vs. Christian perspective on who Jesus is, and whether there really is a Trinity. That is a bit beyond what I'm trying to pursue with this question.

That is why I would you to clarify the part of your question that asks "Is he identifying YHWH with the Trinity or with the Father?" Is there any record identifying YHWH with the trinity?

@Dan you cannot boil it down to YHWH being exclusively the Father and Adonai exclusively the Son because there are sufficient instances where the Angel of the Lord is YHWH or the Spirit/Ruach is YHWH.

there is talk of the Spirit of God in the OT, but not so much as a distinct person, but more as the active force of the monotheistic God. This is a statement of opinion.

@NihilSineDeo. Agreed. Am not trying to make a global assessment at this point, and am especially NOT trying to impose any kind of broad YHWH=Father and Adonai=Jesus reading onto the OT. However, in the NT, we do see some of this going on, as Lord is commonly referring to Jesus and in Acts 2:34, this connection is made to the Adonai of Psalm 110. Hence, for now am just curious about the LORD/YHWH in view in Acts 2:34.

Answer
If logically followed, we can see that Peter had God the Father in view in Acts 2:34 when he refers to the YHWH of Psalms 110:1.
Explanation
Peter is often specific when he mentions God.
The usual pattern is:

“God the Father, in sanctification of the Spirit to obedience and
sprinkling of the blood of Jesus Christ” (1 Pet 1:2).


“the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ” (verse 3).


“of God, and of Jesus our Lord” (2 Pet 1:2).

But sometimes he means Jesus:

“of our God and Savior, Jesus Christ” (2 Pet 1:1).

At other times he mentions God as Holy Spirit:

“But Peter said, Ananias, why did Satan fill your heart for you to lie
to the Holy Spirit?” (Acts 5:3).

Conclusion
Since Peter is specific about God, we can be sure that he meant God the Father as the YHWH of Psalms 110:1
Post Script
Since some answers mentioned about the identity of the Adoni/Adonai in Psalms 110:1, I have the following contentions to make:
I state that it is “Adonai” that was originally written in Psalms 110:1 and the supporting points are:
Point 1:-
Both “Adonai” and “adoni” looked the same in ancient Hebrew until the entrance of Masoretic Jews as the scribes in the Middle Ages.
Until then Hebrew was written only in consonants without any vowels. Vowels were used only orally when the OT was read.
Both “Adonai” and “adoni” look the same when written in Hebrew consonants. For example, if we remove the vowels from both “Adonai” and “adoni” in English itself, they will look “DN” and “DN”.
So, we have two historical considerations to make:
When was the vowels added in written form permanently in the OT?
In the Middle Ages when the Christians were stating that Jesus of Nazareth is the Messiah.
Who added the vowels permanently in the OT?
The Masoretic Jews who were familiar with the Christians who stated that Jesus of Nazareth is the Messiah.
So, chances are there they added the vowels of “adoni” instead of “Adonai”.
(I am in no way downplaying the exemplary service provided by the Masoretes).
Point 2:-
Who was David’s Lord?
David was a powerful king. He had no one above him except Yahweh. So let us see who was his Lord?

“Oh my soul you have said to Jehovah, You are my Lord” (Psalms
16:2).


“But my eyes are on You, O Jehovah, my Lord; in You I take refuge;
do not make my soul naked” (Psalms 141:8).


“You have seen, O Jehovah; do not keep silence, O Lord, do not
be far from me. Stir Yourself and awaken to my judgment, to my cause,
my God and my Lord” (Psalms 35:22-23).

[Does anyone remember Apostle Thomas declaring his faith in Jesus as “my Lord and my God” in John 20:28?]
It is very clear that Yahweh alone was David’s “my Lord”. There was no other real “my Lord” to David.
So, when David speaks “my Lord” in Psalms 110:1, it definitely is “my Adonai” not adoni.
Point 3:-
The right hand of a person in the Scripture is a very important place to be at.
This is all the more important when somebody is asked to “sit” at the right hand. Let us look at an example from the Scripture:

“And Bathsheba came in to King Solomon to speak to him for Adonijah.
And the king rose up to meet her, and bowed to her, and sat on his
throne, and placed a throne for the king's mother. And she sat at
his right hand” 1 King 2:19).

Bathsheba is no ordinary human to Solomon and Israel. She was the mother of the King. No king will allow any ordinary person to sit on a throne at his right hand unless that person is unique and special.
Then how could we ever think that the very God Almighty, Yahweh, will allow an angel (even an arch-angel) or any person to “sit” at His right hand?
No way!
Why?
Because, Yahweh’s “right hand is high” (Psalms 89:13) and “exalted” (Psalms 118:16) and no one can “sit” there, unless the Person is special or unique (Monogenes)!
If anyone has still doubt, see Whom King David has “set” at his right hand:

“I have set Jehovah always before me; for He is at my right hand:
I shall not be shaken” (Psalms 16:8).

So, the Scripture is very clear. A “lord” cannot sit at the right hand of Yahweh. So it has to be “Adonai”.
Point 4:-
The Greek translation of the OT is known as Septuagint which was translated around 250 years before Christ.
It is significant that the Greek translators used the same Greek word for both Yahweh and Adonai/adoni which is “KURIOS”!
“Kurios said to my Kurios”.
Unless they are crazy, no sensible persons would use the same word for the Almighty Yahweh and an ordinary person in the same sentence. They would have differentiated them.
The fact that they did not differentiate the terms confirms the truth that the second Hebrew word was “Adonai” in fact.
Point 5:-

“The Lord (Adonai) at your right hand” Psalms (110:5).

Who is this?
Verse 1 clearly “defines” and “introduces” the Messiah as the Lord/lord at the right hand of Yahweh. (This is the right hermeneutics, right?)
This cannot be anyone else because IF the Messiah is at the right hand of Yahweh, then Yahweh canNOT be at the right hand of the Messiah. Yahweh will be at the left hand of the Messiah!
So this Messiah who is the “my Lord/lord” of David IS the Adonai or the Lord at the right hand of Yahweh.
A likely objection:-
Some may argue that verse 5 is talking about Yahweh at “your” (that is, David’s) right hand.
But then there is a problem. Verse 7 talks about this same Adonai “shall drink out of the torrent on the way”!
This is talking about a triumphant Messiah who conquers kings and judges them.
If I am not wrong, Yahweh is never depicted as drinking from any torrent. (Objections are welcome).
So the “Adonai” in verse 5 and the supposed “adoni” in verse 1 are the same Person and the same Person is at the same right hand.
And this strongly points to “Adonai” to be the correct word in verse 1.
Adoni is used for human beings and Adonai is used for Yahweh. But in Psalms 110:1, strong chances are there, “Adonai” was used originally.
(Unless someone can disprove my above 5 points, I will stand vindicated).

You've nicely shown that Peter is often connecting God (theos) to the Father. Now you have me curious whether some of these kinds of NT instances are connecting their God reference to an OT passage which uses YHWH. There are always fun topics to dig into! Thanks.

Thanks for the response. +1

In Acts 2:23, 25 Peter is accurately quoting Ps 110 which has three persons involved as follows:

David, who authored the psalm is reporting a conversation between two others, namely, the LORD/YHWH and the Lord/Adoni
The LORD/YHWH
"my Lord" - someone greater than David as the title Adoni = "Lord" requires.

This is confirmed by its regular use in the NT (Matt 22:44, Mark 12:36, Luke 20:42, 43, Acts 2:34, 35, Heb 1:13) where this verse of Ps 110 is consistently understood to be about Jesus as Messiah who is the Lord.  Further, the NT consistently uses the phrase, "my Lord" to address Jesus, as per John 20:13, 28, Luke 1:43, Phil 3:8; Matt 22:44, Mark 12:36, Luke 20:42; Acts 2:34.
That is, the verse is NOT about David, and cannot be, because "my Lord" is clearly someone other, and greater, than David.
Now, the OP asks about the identity of YHWH in Ps 110.  Whether one is unitarian, binitarian or trinitarian, this is understood to be the Father.  [However, the identity of "my Lord" varies depending on which unitarian/Arian is asked.]
The Pulpit commentary sums this situation well -

Verse 1. - The LORD said unto my Lord. Jehovah said unto him who is my
Lord and Master, i.e. to Messiah, who is my liege Lord, although about
to be, in some mysterious way, my descendant. Sit thou at my right
hand. An exaltation too high for any merely human personage (comp.
Acts 2:33; 7:56; Heb 1:3).

Other Examples
There are other examples of YHWH speaking to YHWH such as:

Zech 2:6-12 – the LORD (= YHWH) claims three times that He has been sent by the LORD. For example, V8 says: For this is what the LORD of Hosts says: “… Then you will know that the LORD of Hosts has sent Me.”
Isa 48:11-16 – again, the LORD has been sent by the LORD.
Hos 1:7 – the LORD saves by the LORD their God.
Prov 30:1-4 – the Son of God is as unfathomable as God Himself.
Ps 45 (quoted by Heb 1) talks about the “Son” being God in addition to God the Father.


None of this could apply to David is further evidenced by another quotation from Scripture. David did not ascend into the heavens as Jesus did, but he prophesied that exaltation of Jesus in Psalm 110:1.
Again, David could not be speaking of himself for he said, "The Lord said unto my Lord, Sit thou at my right hand, until I my enemies thy footstool." Plus Jesus also referred to Psalm 110:1 in Luke 20:41-44 where He recognized that David called his greater Son "Lord." (See also Matthew 22:42-45; Mark 12:36,37.)
Btw, regarding, "David calling his greater Son "Lord" when Jesus ask the Jews at Matthew 22:45, "If David then calls Him Lord, how is He his son?" At vs46, "And no one was able to answer Him a word."
In regards to Acts 2:36, "Therefore let all the house of Israel know for certain that God has made Him both Lord and Christ--this Jesus whom you crucified." The conclusion Peter drew is that Joel's prophecy was being fulfilled. Jesus is Lord on whom all must call for salvation, (Acts 2:21.)
It should also be mentioned that I have heard for years from Acts 2:36, "Therefore let all the house of Israel know for certain that God has "MADE" Him/Jesus both Lord and Christ." What exactly does that mean? The reason I ask is because Luke 2:11 states, "for today in the city of David there has been born for you a Savior, WHO IS CHRIST THE LORD."

Great to hear the defense of Jesus, as the second Lord who is being referred to, but I remain eager for feedback on the question which I was pressing. From a Christian perspective, who does Peter have in view as the LORD in his citation of Psalm 110: the Father, the Trinity, or neither?

@Dan More. Peter has God the Son in view as I explained from the context of the verses.

"The Lord said unto my Lord." There are two Lords identified in this passage. I affirm that Peter is linking the object of the sentence, "my Lord," to Jesus. But who is Peter referring to as the subject of the sentence, "the Lord," who is doing the talking?

Only one Lord at Matthew 22:42-45. The context, vs42, What do you think about the Christ, whose son is He? The Jews said, The son of David." He's the Son of David in the human sense because Jesus came from David's line. Jesus then says, how does David in the Spirit call Him Lord? At vs44 Jesus brings up Psalm 110:1 and says at vs45, "If David then calls Him Lord, how is He/Jesus Christ his son? What Jesus is doing is applying Psalm 110:1 to Himself. Remember Jesus first ask what do you think about the Messiah/Christ, vs45. At vs46, the Jews were unable to answer Him, Jesus is David's Lord/God

We seem to be talking past each other. The question is with regard to Acts 2:34.

@DanMoore I already gave my answers so I will leave at that. And remember, it was you who brought up Psalm 110:1. I simply explained on how it comes into play with your initial question regarding Acts 2:34.

Consider the alternate and unreasonable reading of Acts 2:34-35 if the second lord of Psalm 110:1 is Adonai, does the reading "God made this Jesus whom you crucified, both YHWH and messiah"  make sense? The assumption without proof that Jesus was called Adonai in Psalm 110:1 and Acts 2:34-35 is not true. Peter or any prophets, apostles or disciples never identified Jesus as the Adonai of the bible as Acts 3:13 shows
Acts 3:13 ASV
The God of Abraham, and of Isaac, and of Jacob, the God of our fathers, hath glorified his Servant Jesus; whom ye delivered up, and denied before the face of Pilate, when he had determined to release him.
Peter did not believe that the trinity or Jesus or holy spirit is the God of Abraham, and of Isaac, and of Jacob, the God of their fathers. Acts 3:13 shows that Jesus is God's servant. There is no record in the bible for the only true God to speak to another who is equally the only true God. The capitalization on the second lord of Psalm 110:1 is misleading.
Examining Psalm 110:1 we find the 1st LORD in Psalm 110:1 is Jehovah/YHWH. The second lord is translated from the Hebrew word adoni. The word adoni is a title which never refers to God. The word  Adoni  means (my lord) The Father is never addressed as adoni. The title adoni is for someone who is explicitly not God. Therefore, the capital on the second lord [adoni] in Psalm 110:1 can be characterized as an interpretation.
Most appearances of the word "adoni" in the Old Testament has been use to refer to a human superior, husband, king or master. It has never ever been used to refer to God.
Peter affirmed the fulfillment of this verse in Acts 2:32-36. If we assume that Peter believed that both the YHWH/the Father and Jesus are God, then God permitted God to die. Then God resurrected God and God sat God at God's right hand.
Acts 2:32-36 YLT
'This Jesus did God raise up, of which we are all witnesses; at the right hand then of God having been exalted -- also the promise of the Holy Spirit having received from the Father -- he was shedding forth this, which now ye see and hear; for David did not go up to the heavens, and he saith himself: The Lord saith to my lord, Sit thou at my right hand, till I make thy foes thy footstool; assuredly, therefore, let all the house of Israel know, that both Lord and Christ did God make him -- this Jesus whom ye did crucify.'
Adonai and adoni are variations of Masoretic pointing to distinguish divine reference from human. Adonai is referred to God but adoni to human superiors. Adoni-refers to men: my lord, my master [zee Ps.110:1]. Adonai --ref.to God...Lord." "Adon (lord), Brown, Driver, Briggs, Hebrew and English Lexicon of the Old Testament.
"Lord" The International Standard Bible Encyclopedia, Eerdmans, 1986, 3:157. Adonai with a short vowel is the rare plural of adoni and appears as a title for the angels in Gen. 19:2 Uncertainty as to the pointing as a divine or human title is very rare.
"The form 'to my lord,' l'adoni is never used in the Old Testament as a divine reference...The generally accepted fact[is] that the Masoretic pointing distinguishes divine references(adonai) from human references(adoni) George Wigram, The Englishman's Hebrew and Chaldee Concordance of the Old Testament, cited in Herbert Bateman, "Psalm 110:1 and the New Testament," Biblioteca Sacra, Oct.-Dec.,1992, 438.
LORD” or “the LORD” in the OT represents (YHWH) God. This is not to be confused with the Greek word Kurios, which is used of Jesus and is a title of respect, honor and authority. The title “Lord” is used of many people in the Bible not just God and Jesus. God made Jesus both lord and Christ.
The consistent translation of Hebrew l'adoni  "to my lord" to the Greek "kurios mou" shows that the Greek translation consistently finds the Hebrew adoni as my lord.
Please see the following verses to examine if the Greek translation of l'adoni to "kurios mou" is complicated or corrupted.
Gen.24:35,54,56,; Gen.32:4,5,18; Gen.44:9,16,33
1 Sam.24:6; 25:27,28,30,31
2 Sam.4:8; 19:28
1 Kings1:2; 18:13; 20:9
1 Chronicles 21:3
Psalm 110:1
Matthew 22:44-45 shows Jesus asking "If then David doth call him lord, how is he his son?' To claim that the second lord in Psalm 110 :1 is Adonai and not adoni would then make David the father of YHWH /Adonai. We have Jesus indicating that David's lord is also David's son. The idea that David was the Father of YHWH /Adonai is not present in verses cited or the rest of the bible.
The asker states "Since Peter is shifting (or clarifying) the referent of Adonai, is he also shifting (or clarifying) the referent of YHWH, at least for his understanding of Psalm 110:1?
Peter did not shift the referent of Adonai. There is no evidence the Peter shifted the referent of YHWH, at least for his understanding of Psalm 110:1.

This factually incorrect on several levels - but first, who is the second "Lord" in Ps 110:1 - it cannot be David because David calls him "my Lord" - so who is it?

Further, אָדוֹן and אֲדֹנָי is more than a difference in Masoretic pointing!

Rhis doies not answer the question - who is the send "Lord" in Ps 110:1?

@Dottard. The trinity which the OP assume is in the bible is factually not in the bible. An answer that assumes that the trinity is in the bible which is factually not there is factually an assumption without evidence.

I refuse to go down rabbit holes with you again - you have not answered the question - who the "the Lord" in Ps 110:1 and Acts 2:34.  Perhaps if you would at least engage with the questions at hand rather than defending your position, people might be more willing to engage with you.

@Dootard. The question is about the trinity which is factually not in the bible. Is there any record in the bible identifying YHWH with the trinity?

Peter misquotes Psalm 16:8 in Acts 2:25
I keep my eyes always on the Lord. With him at my right hand, I will not be shaken.
This misquote leads into the incorrect understanding of Psalm 110.
In Psalm 16 it is David who sits at the right hand of the LORD, and therefore Psalm 110 is a Psalm written to be sung about King David.
Peter doesn’t have a flipping clue what the Trinity is in Acts 2. He is mentioning the Psalms as though everything is about the Father and Jesus. Peter understands King David as being the prophet whom speaks of Jesus.
Verses 29-31 Fellow Israelites, I can tell you confidently that the patriarch David died and was buried, and his tomb is here to this day. 30 But he was a prophet and knew that God had promised him on oath that he would place one of his descendants on his throne. 31 Seeing what was to come, he spoke of the resurrection of the Messiah, that he was not abandoned to the realm of the dead, nor did his body see decay.
Peter’s reasoning is that because King David was not resurrected from the dead, that he could not have been the Lord and Messiah. Jesus did that and so Jesus is the Lord and Messiah.
Peter is not speaking about the Trinity. Read Acts 2:22 very closely. Peter says Jesus was a man. In the Trinity theology Jesus was not a man, Jesus was God.
Fellow Israelites, listen to this: Jesus of Nazareth was a man accredited by God to you by miracles, wonders and signs, which God did among you through him, as you yourselves know. This man was handed over to you by God’s deliberate plan and foreknowledge; and you, with the help of wicked men, put him to death by nailing him to the cross. But God raised him from the dead, freeing him from the agony of death, because it was impossible for death to keep its hold on him.

Flipping clue? Actually the OT is sufficiently indicative that there are three who share the same will. “Come ye near unto me (God narrating #1), hear ye this; I have not spoken in secret from the beginning; from the time that it was, there am I(#1): and now the Lord GOD(#2), and his Spirit(#3), hath sent me(#1).”
‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭48‬:‭16‬ ‭there are many more such examples in translated texts and more still in the Hebrew that don’t come through in the translated text. The Trinity is undoubtedly an OT truth and those who have ears and eyes to see and hear will not deny that which is written

In Trinitarian understanding Jesus was both a man because he had an earthly human housing and God because God who is spirit inhabited that earthly housing but having suppressed voluntarily His divine attributes. He was also not the Father and not the Holy Spirit. You ought to first study the basics of Trinitarian doctrine before making your argument lest your argument be riddled with errors and thereby discredit your credibility.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
